# How can i use icons from vuejs3?

Tags: css, vuejs3, element-plus

I want to use `icons-vue` so i installed with this command: yarn add @element-plus/icons-vue

this is the documentation: https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/icon.html#icon-usage

but when i refreshed the page i can not see the icons, how can i show the icons?

i tried to use globally

```
import ElementPlusIcons from '@element-plus/icons-vue'
...
createApp(App)
  
  .use(ElementPlusIcons)
```

but does not work

```
<el-menu-item >
            <el-icon>  <edit></edit></el-icon>
</el-menu-item>
```

my project is not recognizing that library

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would require to use unplug-elementplus plug in (https://github.com/element-plus/unplugin-element-plus).

And manually import icons in any component to take full advantage of tree shaking.

Please refer to https://element-plus.org/en-US/guide/quickstart.html#manually-import

Also, note that element plus is built for vue3

Comment: i want the icons not the elements

Comment: @PavaJ i am using vue3

Comment: Yes, you may use below statement in a component: import ElementPlusIcons from '@element-plus/icons